# Multiple lines in cmd for windows docker

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I want to write this line in multiple rows

```
CMD ".\foo.exe; .\bar.exe; .\baz.exe"
```

I am using a windows base image and I think all dockerfile commands are run in powershell.

I have tried

```
CMD ".\foo.exe; \n\
        .\bar.exe; \n\ 
        .\baz.exe"
```

This could get built but not run as it was not recognized as a cmdlet

And

```
CMD ".\foo.exe; `
        .\bar.exe; ` 
        .\baz.exe"
```

This could not get built as docker did not understand it

How do I do it?